# Separated commas array as different string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have separated by commas array, and needed to separate each word into separate construction.

For example:

```
Author1, Author2, Author3
```

To:

```
<meta content="Author1">
<meta content="Author2">
<meta content="Author3">
```

Trying this:

```
<?php
$ex = explode(',', $input);
foreach ($ex as $authorc) {
echo '<meta content="$ex">';
}
```

Recieved this:

```
<meta content="$ex"><meta content="$ex">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: look into explode and foreach

Comment: Could you post the var_dump() of the array so we can take a look at the structure?

Comment: Added to post code, that i try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo '<meta content="$ex">';
```

with

```
echo '<meta content="'.$authorc.'">';
```

Comment: That was simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: Accepted. Also, how can i add end of line, that not separate last string?

Comment: You can try: echo '<meta content="'.$authorc.'">\n';